# Jquery select all values in a multiselect dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a multi-select html dropdown.  I want to programatically (via jquery) select all values in the dropdown. How can I do this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Where the select has the id test

```
$('#test option').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/et3hH/)

Or as Ryan mentioned you can use `.prop`

```
$('#test option').prop('selected', true); // or pass false to deselect them
```

Comment: Worth noting the difference between `attr` and `prop`. Using `selected` as an attribute only sets the initial state of it upon introduction to the DOM — for any changes to its state after that point, use `prop`. For example: `.prop('selected', true)`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do `$("#dropdown").val([0, 1, 2, 3])` where `0`, `1`, `2`, `3` the values you want to select.

Comment: What if I want to select them all (arbitrary amount).  Could you please show me how to do this as I am unsure still.  Would I have to manually construct that array by looping through all the selections?

Comment: @john: InfernalBadger's answer would be more appropriate :)