# Select all multi-select Option using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I tried to select all options of multi-slect `flower[ ]` using javascript but nothing happened when I click on submit, please tell what wrong ?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            $("#submit").click(function() {

                $('#flower option').each(function() {
                    $(this).attr('selected', true);
                });

            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form method="Get" action="#">
            <select name="flower[ ]" id="flower" multiple>
                <option value="flower">FLOWER</option>
                <option value="rose">ROSE</option>
                <option value="lilly">LILLY</option>
                <option value="jasmine">JASMINE</option>
                <option value="lotus">LOTUS</option>
                <option value="tulips">TULIPS</option>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Are there any error messages? Also note you may be refreshing the page when you submit a form, clearing changes made to the page. Try doing `event.preventDefault()` and give your function an `event` parameter. Also try doing a test case, for example do `console.log()` in the functions you thing are not working, to check they are being ran.

Answer (score 2):

You must put your javscript click function inside document ready function. Like this

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#submit").click(function(e){
      $('#flower option').each(function () {
         $(this).attr('selected', true);
      });
   });
 });
```

Cheers.. :)

Answer (score 2):

You are missing:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

above your script and then close it with:

```
});
```

but as mentioned above:

```
$('#flower option').attr('selected', true);
```

Should do the trick as well

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#flower option').attr('selected', true);
```

You've already selected all of the options so the each loop is unnecessary.

Comment: The OP may want to research how jQuery works, once you grasp why this answer is correct, jQuery will really 'click' for you :-) no pun intended!

Comment: How so? We can;t debug with phrases like "It's broken pls fix"

Comment: *"I tried to select all options of multi-slect `flower[ ]` using javascript but nothing happened when I click..."*. You're telling him that he already selected them, but he's saying nothing happens when he clicks. The reason for it is that the handler is never bound.

Comment: Ah yes because it's binding on something that doesn't exist yet. Oh well other people took care of it.

Answer (score 1):

You do not specify in your question, but it looks like you are using jQuery.  If you do, first make sure that you have placed your code inside of a `$(document).ready(function(){...})` block so that you are waiting until the DOM is ready for you to begin attaching event listeners.  Also, you shouldn't need the `.each(function(){...})` call.  Finally, to ensure cross-browser compatibility and to conform to standards, set the `selected` attribute to `'selected'` rather than `true`.  See code below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#submit').click(function() {
    $('#flower option').attr('selected', 'selected');
  });
});
```

**EDIT**
Actually, it's better to use jQuery's `.prop()` here, since using `.attr()` only is only to be used for setting the option's initial state.  So...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#submit').click(function() {
    $('#flower option').prop('selected', true);
  });
});
```

More info on this can be found in this question...
[Jquery select all values in a multiselect dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5492542/jquery-select-all-values-in-a-multiselect-dropdown)

Answer (score 1):

Put your javascript on the end of body or use $(document).ready(). It must be executed when form is already rendered.

You can do it with .val(). $('#flower').val(ARRAY OF VALUES), i.e.

```
 $('#flower').val(['lilly', 'lotus']);
```

For selecting all you can use

```
$('#flower').val($('#flower option').map(function(){
    return $(this).attr('value');
}));
```